# Available RAM not being used

Tags: ram

I am running a program that takes a significant amount of time to complete.  According to my system monitor, only 20% of the available memory is being used (1.6GiB out of 7.7GiB available).

I'm wondering why is the available memory not being used?  Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the program have configurable options or use other programs such as MySQL where you can allocate more memory to caches, etc that will increase the speed of operations?

Answer (score 4):

It probably doesn't need that much RAM.

If I write a program that opens a file with a random filename, writes "Hi there, Moon!", and closes that file cleanly, and repeats that a couple of million times, It would use very little memory, but will take a lot of time.